# Regex for unicode character like \xe2\x98\xba

Tags: php, regex, unicode

Can any one help me to write a `preg_match` rules to detect whether an input string is a unicode code character?

Here is the list of characters:

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9728&number=128&utf8=string-literal

I want to write a methods to detect whether the input string is a emoticons

```
function detectEmoticons($input) {
    if (preg_match("/REGEX/", $input)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

If the input is a string like "\xe2\x98\x80" or "\xe2\x98\x81"... etc (all the chacracter available in the list  http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9728&number=128&utf8=string-literal) then it should return

```
TRUE
```

Thanks in Advance,
Uttam

Comment: Is the string content literally `\xe2\x98\x80`, or do you mean a PHP string literal `"\xe2\x98\x80"`, which then contains the UTF-8 encoded character "☀"?

Comment: No, it's like "\xe2\x98\x80".

Comment: That's not a "Unicode character" then, it's a byte escape sequence for one...

Answer (score 5):

First, use the `u` modifier if you want your regular expression to work with unicode. Second, use a character class for all characters in the range `[\x{2600}-\x{267F}]` (i.e. U+2600 to U+267F). Now you can write your function as:

```
function detectEmoticons($input){
    if(preg_match("/[\x{2600}-\x{267F}]/u", $input)){
    return TRUE;
    }
    else{
    return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SharanyaDutta Nice one, learned something! Would have done `preg_match('~\xE2[\x98-\x99][\x80-\xBF]~', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

For match Unicode characters in a Regular expressions you must add the **u** Modifier

Example:

```
function detectEmoticons($input) {
    if (preg_match("/REGEX/u", $input)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

If you must retrieve one of the set you could pass the character range like

```
/[\x{START}-\x{END}]/u
```

Or check all characters with the mb_strpos function

Example

```
function detectEmoticons($input) {
    $characters = array("\xe2", "\x98", ...);

    foreach ($characters as $v) {
        if (mb_strpos($input, $v) !== false)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can find the documentation here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php

Comment: I think the OP is looking for help with writing the regular expression itself, so I'm not sure if this is a valid answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time and effort. I guess Sharanya Dutta has given me the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preg_match("/\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3}/", $input);
```

Use preg_replace to scape

```
preg_replace("/\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3}/",'', $input);
```